# Bounding sum of square roots in function of the sum value

Tags: inequalities, sums-of-squares

Knowing the value of $S=\sum_{k=1}^n s_k$ with $s_k\geq 0$,
is it possible to obtain an upper bound on $\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{s_k}$ better than $n \times \sqrt{\max_{1\leq k\leq n} s_k}$ ?

Comment: the bound you state is not given in terms of $S$, in what sense is it a bound "knowing the value of $S$"?

Comment: You may use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to find the best bound (attained for all $s_k = S/n$) However the question is not suitable for this site; try math.stackexchange.com instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: by the [generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality) (or, more specifically, by the [AM--QM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities)), $\sqrt{nS}$ is an upper bound on $\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{s_k}$, which is better than
$n\sqrt{\max_{1\le k\le n}s_k}$.